# Node fetch retry (3 attempts) only after failure of another retry (10 attempts) / Should I use throw new err() on that 10th try?

Tags: node.js, retry-logic

My apologies beforehand, because I'm finding it a bit difficult to explain the question at hand, so I'll divide it in parts.

I'm trying to find the best way to trigger retries based on a failed final retry attempt from another function (retry of a series of retries). What I'm thinking would work is to put something like throw new Err('Forfeit') within the else statement of each retry function (see codes for 1 and 2), then have the original call retry based on that (since there's a condition when it reaches the max attempt). Will that work? How would you approach it?

1. I created my own retry function below (n=3 attempts):

   ```
    function retryFetchAttempt(attempt, maxAttempts, myFunction, error) {

    if (attempt < maxAttempts) {
        setTimeout(function() {
            myFunction()
            .then(result => console.log('Retry: ', attempt))
            .catch(err => {
                  console.log(err);
                  attempt += 1;
                  retryFetchAttempt(attempt, maxAttempts, myFunction, error)
                }
            )
        }, 2000 ** attempt);
    } else {
        console.log('Forfeited at retry: ', attempt, error);
        // throw new Err('Forfeit'); ????
    }
    }

    module.exports = {
      retryFetchAttempt
    }
   ```
2. I created another retry for each email being sent (10 attempts).

   ```
    const {google} = require('googleapis');
    const nodemailer = require('nodemailer');

    function retryEmail(attempt, sender, emailRecipients, bccRecipients, getSubject, htmlOutput, refreshToken, clientid, client_secret, REDIRECT_URI) {

    const maxRetries = 10;
    if (attempt < maxRetries) {
        setTimeout(function() {
            sendEmail(
                sender,
                emailRecipients,
                bccRecipients,
                getSubject,
                htmlOutput,
                refreshToken,
                clientid,
                client_secret,
                REDIRECT_URI
            ).then(result => console.log('Email sent after retry: ', attempt, result))
            .catch(err => {
                  console.log(err);
                  attempt += 1;
                  retryEmail(
                    attempt,
                    sender,
                    emailRecipients,
                    bccRecipients,
                    getSubject,
                    htmlOutput,
                    refreshToken,
                    clientid,
                    client_secret,
                    REDIRECT_URI)
                }
            )
        }, 3000);
    } else {
        console.log('Forfeited at retry: ', attempt);
        // throw new Err('Forfeit'); ????
    }
   }

    async function sendEmail(sender, emailRecipients, bccRecipients, getSubject, htmlOutput, refreshToken, clientid, client_secret, REDIRECT_URI) {

    try {
        const oAuth2Client = new google.auth.OAuth2(clientid, client_secret, REDIRECT_URI);
        oAuth2Client.setCredentials({refresh_token: refreshToken});
        const accessToken = await oAuth2Client.getAccessToken();

        let smtpConfigWithToken = {
            host: 'smtp.gmail.com',
            port: 465,
            secure: true,
            //pool: true,
            auth: {
                type: 'OAuth2',
                user: sender,
                clientId: clientid,
                clientSecret: client_secret,
                refreshToken: accessToken.res.data.refresh_token,
                accessToken: accessToken.res.data.accessToken
            }
        };

        let transporter = nodemailer.createTransport(smtpConfigWithToken);

        let HelperOptions = {
            from: sender,
            to: emailRecipients,
            bcc: bccRecipients,
            subject: getSubject,
            html: htmlOutput
        };

        const result = transporter.sendMail(HelperOptions);
        return result;
    } catch(err) {
        return err;
    }
   }

   module.exports = {
     sendEmail,
     retryEmail
   }
   ```
3. I have a node cron job that triggers Mon-Fri at 11:30am UTC - 300. This job uses node-fetch to call another route that queries the database.
   That fetch call uses the 3 attempts retry. See the code below:

   // CRON schedule to run MON-FRI at 11:30am UTC - 300
   // Reminder of returning equipment 7 days after being loaned
   // Also removes the 'snooze' status after 7 days (if snooze was applied)

   ```
    cron.schedule('30 11 * * 1,2,3,4,5', () => {
    let retryAttempt = 0;
    const maxAttempts = 3;

    async function scheduler() {
      try {
        const fetchResult = await fetch(process.env.REDIRECT_URI + config.route1, {
          method: 'GET',
          headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            'auth-token': process.env.API_TOKEN
          },
        });
        const response = await fetchResult;
        const jsonData = await response.json();
        console.log(jsonData)
      } catch(e) {
        console.log('')
      }
    }

    scheduler()
      .then(sch => console.log('Fetch Email reminder'))
      .catch(err => retryFetchAttempt(retryAttempt, maxAttempts, scheduler, ''))

    });
   ```
4. The following route is called by the 1st fetch call. This one generates a call forEach DB record that matches the parameters. Then, it'll trigger a reminder via email. See the code below:

   // Route used by cron at 11:30am (Mon-Fri) to send email reminders about non-returned equipment

   ```
    router.get(config.route1, (req, res) => {
    let retryAttempt = 0;
    const maxAttempts = 3;

    async function fetchEachScheduled() {
      try {
        await postgres('metsupply').select('*').then(data => {
          if (data[0] !== undefined) {
            data.forEach(async (record, index) => {
              try {
                setTimeout(async function() {
                  try {
                    const fetchResult = await fetch(process.env.REDIRECT_URI + config.route2, {
                      method: 'POST',
                      headers: {
                        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                        'auth-token': process.env.API_TOKEN
                      },
                      body: JSON.stringify({
                        record: record,
                        index: index
                      })
                    });
                    const response = await fetchResult;
                    const jsonData = await response.json();
                    console.log(jsonData)
                  } catch(e) {
                    console.log(e)
                    console.log(record)
                  }
                }, 1000 * index)
              } catch(e) {
                console.log(e)
              }
            })
          } else {
            console.log(`Job finished at ${new Date().toString().split(" GMT",1)} -- No data`)
          }
          res.json('Closed query');
        })
      } catch(e) {
        console.log(e)
      }
    }

    fetchEachScheduled()
      .then(sch => console.log('Email reminder started'))
      .catch(err => retryFetchAttempt(retryAttempt, maxAttempts, fetchEachScheduled, ''))
    })
   ```
5. Finally (yes... Finally!). The function below processes the forEach call.

   ```
    router.post(config.route2, async (req, res) => {
    try {
    const {
      record,
      index
    } = req.body;

    const currentDate = new Date();
    const currentDateString = currentDate.toString().split(" GMT",1);
    let retryAttempt = 0;
    const recordDate = new Date(record.jsdate.toString());
    recordDate.setDate(recordDate.getDate() + 1);

    const output = emailTemplates.supplyReminder(record);
    const sender = process.env.SUPPLY_SENDER;
    const emailRecipients = config.emailRecipient;
    const bccRecipients = [];
    const getSubject = 'Return equipment reminder';
    const refreshToken = process.env.SUPPLY_REFRESH_TOKEN;
    const clientid = process.env.SUPPLY_CLIENT_ID;
    const client_secret = process.env.SUPPLY_CLIENT_SECRET;
    const REDIRECT_URI = process.env.REDIRECT_URI;


    if ((currentDate >= recordDate) && (record.returned === 'No') && (record.needtoreplace === 'No') && (record.requesttype === 'Loan') && (record.snooze === 'No') && (record.notificationsoff === 'No')) {
      setTimeout(async function() {
        await sendEmail(
          sender,
          emailRecipients,
          bccRecipients,
          getSubject,
          output,
          refreshToken,
          clientid,
          client_secret,
          REDIRECT_URI
        ).then(async result => {
          //console.log('Email sent...', result);
        })
        .catch(err => {
            retryAttempt += 1;
            retryEmail(
              retryAttempt,
              sender,
              emailRecipients,
              bccRecipients,
              getSubject,
              output,
              refreshToken,
              clientid,
              client_secret,
              REDIRECT_URI
              );
          }
        )
      }, 1000);
      postgres(config.maindb).update('emailcount', record.emailcount + 1).where('requestid', record.requestid).then(async counter => {
        res.json(`Job finished at ${new Date().toString().split(" GMT",1)} -- Sending Email`)
      }).catch(e => console.log(e))
    }
    if ((currentDate < recordDate) && (record.returned === 'No') && (record.needtoreplace === 'No') && (record.requesttype === 'Loan') && (record.snooze === 'No') && (record.notificationsoff === 'No')) {
      res.json(`Job finished at ${new Date().toString().split(" GMT",1)} -- Nothing to send -- Time is not up`)
    }
    if ((record.snooze === 'Yes') && (new Date().getTime() - new Date(record.lastmodified).getTime() >= (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 7))) {
      await postgres(config.maindb).update({
        emailcount: record.emailcount + 1,
        snooze: 'No'
      }).where('requestid', record.requestid)
      .then(counter => {
        res.json(`Job finished at ${new Date().toString().split(" GMT",1)} -- Nothing to send -- Snooze: ${new Date().getTime() - new Date(record.lastmodified).getTime()}`)
      })
      .catch(e => console.log(e))
    }
    if ((record.returned === 'Yes') || (record.needtoreplace === 'Yes') || (record.notificationsoff === 'Yes') || (record.requesttype === 'Replace')) {
      res.json(`Job finished at ${new Date().toString().split(" GMT",1)} -- Nothing to send`)
    }
   } catch(e) {
     console.log(e)
   }
   })
   ```